# zoom changes vertical position of the mat-select drop-down. How to fix it for all zooms?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

As you can see on the image, the left drop-down is the 100% zoom size, but when I decrease the zoom 90% the drop-down vertical position change to below

[image: the screen]

So, I would like to fix the position for all zoom sizes. Can anyone help me please?

I tried setting with the next code

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}
```

but it is not solve when the zoom changes.

Comment: You need to post more code so we can reproduce the error and then help you fix it. Right now we can just guess what's going on.